# Dissolving featurecollection in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, dissolve

Here is the link to my GEE code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/99b494aacf00df398e0e710ec02c13e8

Here is the code (DMDP is an asset and to see it please follow the link):

```
Map.centerObject(DMDP, 9)

// -----------------     ADD BOUNDARY LINES TO DISPLAY     -----------------

// Create an empty image into which to paint the features, cast to byte.
var empty = ee.Image().byte();

var outLn_dmdp = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: DMDP,
  color: 0,
  width: 1 
});
Map.addLayer(outLn_dmdp, {palette: 'red'}, 'DMDP');
```

I know that I can easily dissolve the DMDP featurecollection (i.e. shapefile) in ArcGIS or QGIS. But I am wondering if there is a way to dissolve DMDP (i.e. featurecollection) in Google Earth Engine, so that I can display only the boundary of the featurecollection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your simplest solution is the following.

```
 var joinedFeatures = DMDP.union()
 Map.addLayer(joinedFeatures)
```

Then set the colours that you prefer before adding it to the map.