# Union polygons in Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, dissolve

I am trying to compare the NDVI-values of different land cover classes over a certain time period and display it in a chart. 
So in a first step, I'd like to extract the crop land cover and  use its geometry to calculate just the NDVI of the croplands
This is my code so far.

```
var area = ee.FeatureCollection('users/jonathanreith/KK')
Map.centerObject(area,9);
var lc  = ee.Image("ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3").select('landcover');

var crop = lc.eq(30)

// Convert the crop landcover to vectors.
var crop = crop.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: area,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'landcover',
  scale: 300
});

print(crop)
var cropu = crop.union(1)
print(cropu)

//chart
var NDVITimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: l8,
    regions: cropu,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
});
```

Unfortunately, crop consists of thousands of features, while union somehow erases all the information and just leaves the outer bounding box.

So how do I create an union feature with its geometries intact?
My [Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8c777a62b734f4e283b544ea09ce0dd0)
I already checked these Q&As:

- [Dissolving featurecollection in google earth engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310355); and
- [Polygons vs MultiPolygons in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250431)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, you need a MultiPoint Feature for the TimeSeries.
I think you just need to filter the 'crop' FeatureCollection from reduceToVectors for the features containing the crop landcover by:

```
crop = crop.filter(ee.Filter.equals('landcover',1))
```

then you can extract the feauteres as one MultiPolygon with:

```
var cropu = crop.geometry()
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped! After I created cropu I wanted to combine it with forest (two MultiPolygons) into one FeatureCollection in order to use it as a region in the chart. Even though both have distinct geometries, They are not separated in the chart. Any ideas why this is not working. https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca7fd0c4bcbda39fec8b88ccb6516e93

Comment: You either have to mask your landcover layers before reduceToVectors:
`crop = crop.updateMask(crop)`
`forest = forest.updateMask(forest)`
https://code.earthengine.google.com/28c43d8acd0fe9134413fc83dbbd8cc3

or filter the features afterwards:
`crop = crop.filter(ee.Filter.equals('landcover',1))
forest = forest.filter(ee.Filter.equals('landcover',1))`
https://code.earthengine.google.com/30b50d51529ce9b8d1aebe73ef2898ce